# MySQL Workbench Query Preferences

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: screenshot]

We recently upgraded our MySQL Workbench environment from 5.2 to 6.1.

It works fine, but every query seems to default to columns that are tiny, so that the result of every query has me opening up each column so I can see the data.

When we had 5.2, the columns would make an attempt to fill the viewing window.

Does anyone know how to fix this behavior in the many settings that Workbench has?

I tried asking this with an account I have had for a while on [MySQL Forums :: MySQL Workbench](http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?113), but the system says I am not authorized to post or reply to topics there.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Perhaps, but programmers (like me) are the ones who use Workbench on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug tracker with this issue open :

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72332

> Open a SQL editor to a server and execute a query that returns some
>   text fields, the columns don't autofit to a reasonable width to
>   display as much as they can (or set in the Preferences as I believe
>   256 bytes..). Instead they are displayed in a super narrow table
>   taking 1/20 of the screen width.

It seems to have changed with 6.1

Subscribe to updates! And roll back to 6.0.8 ;-)

Comment: That sounds like the option I will need to go, then. I am now subscribed.

Answer (score 2):

seems like there is a way to do it with the `wrap cell contents`

see documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-query-panel.html

Answer (score 1):

Fixed as of the `MySQL Workbench 6.2.0` release

Source: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72332

Comment: Yes it is! I was subscribed to that bug, and I updated as soon as they posted the fix. Thanks for posting that here, Bhavin! :)